# How to end CircleCI run task after specific output / time

Tags: continuous-integration, discord.js, circleci

I'm using CircleCI and discord.js. This is my config.yml file:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node
      
      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/5thgradebot

    steps:

      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install
        
      # run tests!
      - run: npm run start

      - run: circleci-agent step halt
```

At run: npm run start, the run start is supposed to run forever, but I don't want it to run forever in CircleCI. Is there anyway to end the run task after it sees a specific output. For example, "Logged in as DiscordBot#1984"

Comment: One simple approach is to use `timeout` and give the `npm` command the maximum amount of time your tests would take to run, plus a bit of extra in case it is running slowly.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Assuming `npm run start` is the command you wish to limit, try `timeout 5m npm run start`, for 5 minutes. Use `timeout --help` for your time options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @halfer for the answer:

Assuming npm run start is the command you wish to limit, try timeout 5m npm run start, for 5 minutes. Use timeout --help for your time options.